# Denwer перестал прописывать домены

Tags: denwer

Проблема в Denwer'е
Давно не запускал, месяца 2 назад всё работало.
Он стартует, но домены не прописывает в host.
В файле AddedHosts.txt домены прописаны и каталоги присутствуют. А вот в etc/hosts Denwer их не прописывает.

Почему так происходит?  Или только реинсталл?

P.S. host-файл открыт на редактирование и редактируется нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю почему, политика безопасности одинаковая у каталогов, но стоило только сделать копию каталога с сайтом и переименовать на старое название, предварительно удалив старый каталог, как все заработало и каталоги стали попадать в список доменов в Denwer!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, отсутствуют права на запись в файл. От себя порекомендую использовать вместо Денвера вот это: [Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com)

Comment: А кто бы их менял?

Answer (score -1):

Denwer никогда ничего и нигде вам делать не должен! Это изначально локальная сборка для тестирования. И вас там об этом предупреждают!